# Google Map in Android without overlapping the place markers

Tags: android, google-maps

http://s8.postimg.org/sxnf7b751/Question.png

This is an example of maps using android (Google Maps), Which contain Overlapping markers. Can i represent the whole same data with the maps without overlapping ? (Without overlays or spiderify).

Thanks.

Comment: you always want to show those markers or do you mean grouping them together?

Comment: Thanks for responding,i don't want grouping and overlapping of markers.. while zooming it shows perfectly as separated, but at this zoom level, the markers are overlapping. I just want another way to represent that values to the places marked, at this zoom level.

Comment: make the markers smaller then, you zoom out the distance between the markers get smaller obviously so what else would you expect to happen

Comment: can we change the markers to a dot and values on a side of map which the dot and Values are connected with a line ? the values should be on side of the app at any zoom level which contain the dot.Is that possible ? I can draw if you want more clarification.

Comment: sure, you are going to update the map everytime the camera changes and thats going to be a lot of overhead

Comment: http://s4.postimg.org/h7znr6ge5/Screenshot_new_question.jpg Like this or any other way..

Comment: markers are just images so no you cant do that

Comment: Is there any other APIs Available for Android Which gives these functionality ? Can you Suggest some other Android API Alternatives for google Maps API ?

Comment: What you want to do cannot he done period, there is no way to not have markers overlap